Why does Jenkins not run under systemd with my user?
I am using a Raspberry Pi 4.
If I run the following command in a terminal everything works fine
java -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war -httpPort=8080
However if I attempt to run it using systemD, having used systemctl edit jenkins to create an override file for the user and group attributes, it does not run the startup to full completion.
This is how my override looks
  GNU nano 7.2                                                 /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/.#override.conf1993a0267a0fb4a7                                                    M     
### Editing /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the contents of the drop-in file
[Service]

User: charlie
Group: charlie

### Edits below this comment will be discarded

This is the output from systemctl status jenkins
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: activating (start) since Mon 2024-06-10 12:59:15 BST; 41s ago
   Main PID: 53113 (java)
      Tasks: 59 (limit: 8686)
     Memory: 510.5M (peak: 510.5M)
        CPU: 2min 1.407s
     CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
             └─53113 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080

Jun 10 12:59:41 jack jenkins[53113]: *************************************************************
Jun 10 12:59:41 jack jenkins[53113]: *************************************************************
Jun 10 12:59:41 jack jenkins[53113]: *************************************************************
Jun 10 12:59:41 jack jenkins[53113]: Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Jun 10 12:59:41 jack jenkins[53113]: Please use the following password to proceed to installation:
Jun 10 12:59:41 jack jenkins[53113]: 78f5a4997e9f4d2dae72352f2fd7d2e4
Jun 10 12:59:41 jack jenkins[53113]: This may also be found at: /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
Jun 10 12:59:41 jack jenkins[53113]: *************************************************************
Jun 10 12:59:41 jack jenkins[53113]: *************************************************************
Jun 10 12:59:41 jack jenkins[53113]: *************************************************************

Note that I have already set Jenkins up running this under my user account from the terminal, so I would expect it to remember these settings when launching it from systemd with my user name.
The login page just says "Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work ..." forever...
